# Trying to make the list `foorbars` dynamic by popping off the last two if a condition is met

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to make a `list` dynamic if a condition is met, not sure if it is entirely possible with python, especially with a list comprehension.

Here is my example code:

```
foobars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: 'foo'
  }
]

all_foos = {
   foobar['id']: foobar['bar']  
   for foobar in foobars if condition == 'x' else foobars.pop(len(foorbars - 2))
}
```

Trying to make the list `foobars` dynamic by popping off the last two if a condition is met.

Essentially, I am trying to remove the last two list items if the django webpage renders in another country.

Open to suggestions and alternatives.
Thanks.

**Main issue is getting the conditional in the dict comprehension, not returning the last two items from the list.**

Comment: Do you mean `foobars = foobars[:-2]`?

Comment: See [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1324033)

Comment: Getting the last 2 items in a list won't be the problem. 

The main issue is having the conditional statement in the dict comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
forbars[:-2]
```

it will not change the actual data and will help you in displaying it without the last 2 elements, BTW the list has 1 element, so I think it would throw an error probably.

Comment: The main issue is adding the conditional statement in the dict comprehension, not necessarily getting the last to elements.